# UWP Windows-10 Unable to see reference added via .vsix

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2015, windows-10-universal, vsix

I have a C# app targeting Windows-10 desktop. The app uses our SDK which is packaged into **.vsix**. I install this .vsix, so that VS-2015 can reference my SDK. Once i install it, I can see it in

> Tools->Extensions and Updates

When I try to add it as a **Reference** to my app, VS doesnt seem to find it.

> *right-click* on References->Add References->Universal Windows->Extensions

I do not see it under **Extensions**

 This used to work flawlessly earlier. Yesterday while running my app, I went to

> *right click* on References -> Add References -> Universal Windows -> Recent

*right click* & ***Clear Recent References***

 Unfortunately, once I cleared Recent References, VS-2015, doesnt show my reference in the list at all & I am not able to add this reference.

I am not sure how to fix this. I restarted VS, but it didnt help. I thought maybe some old values are persisting somewhere in the registry & restarted my machine. As it turns out it didnt help either

Comment: Please try to right-click on References->Add References->Universal Windows->Search Box, and type in your extension's name.

Comment: Hi @JaydenGu, Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, even if I search for my extension in the Search Box, it doesnt show up.

Comment: "our SDK" - what are you referring to? Was it working before? If yes, what was the last change you made (perhaps installed update 3) after which it has stopped working.

Comment: Hi @karann, Thx for the response. We have music recognition/recommendation lib(.dll) which we call SDK. We package this SDK as a .vsix extension & give it to customers who pay for our software. Our customers use the **.vsix** to install our SDK & develop apps using it. Couple days ago I did a **Clear Recent References** and after that I started seeing the issue. Even now I can see our SDK listed under **Tools -> Extensions and Updates**, which means it is installed but I cannot add it as reference to my app. I have VS-2015, **Version 14.0.25123.00 Update 2**